# Is the intersection of a chain of non-small submodules also non-small?

Tags: ring-theory, modules

**Definition** A submodule $N$ of a module $M$ is said to be  small if there is no proper submodule $K$ of $M$ such that $N+K=M$. A submodule which is not small is called as nonsmall submodule.

My Question: Let $M_1\geq M_2\geq\cdots$ be a decending chain of nonsmall submodules of a module $M$. If $N=\cap_{i=1}^{\infty}M_i$, then $N$ is also a nonsmall submodule of $M$.

My Attempt: Since each $M_i$ is nonsmall, each  $M_i$ is nonzero and hence $N$ is also nonzero. Now, I have no idea how to approach.

Give a short proof or a counter example.

Comment: Honestly, it's better not to include things like "It looks trivial but I can't do it. " and things like "thanks in advance."  Maybe it's still polite in formal correspondence but here it's just kind of wasted space.  We'd be interested in seeing you replace it with more of the "thinking" that you had doubts about.

Comment: Also, apparently you meant the intersection of $M_i$, because you did not mention $N_i$ before that(?)

Comment: It's also considered a bit impolite to use phrases in the imperative like "Give a short proof" as if we were an underling or something.  I also improved the title to be something more useful.  The pattern "Question about <thing>" is almost never a good title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since each $M_i$ is nonsmall, each  $M_i$ is nonzero and hence $N$ is also nonzero.

That does not follow.

Let $R=M=\prod_{i=0}^\infty F$ for some field $F$.

Let $e_0=(1,1,1,\ldots)$, $e_1=(0,1,1\ldots)$ $e_2=(0,0,1,1,\ldots)$ and so on for all $i$.

Obviously $e_iR\supseteq e_{i+1}R$ for all $i$.  Each $e_iR$ is nonsmall (since it is a summand of $R$.)

But $\bigcap_{i=0}^\infty e_iR=\{0\}$.

Comment: Thank You so much.